# Find max characters can fit in one line of Android Jetpack compose Text

Tags: android, kotlin, string-length, android-jetpack-compose-text

I want to find the total number of characters that can fit in **one line** of a current Jetpack compose [Text](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/text)

Any field where I can get this information. Thanks

Comment: Are you using a monospaced font? If not, it won't be possible...

Comment: @lukas.j then i can use a monospaced font. What is the solution?

Answer (score -3):

You probably assume that the `Text()` composable is some placeholder (box) with fixed dimensions

[image]

then you place some text into it

[image]

and ask us, how many characters you may use to fit this placeholder.

But things work the other way:

1. There is no `Text()` composable *without* text string in it.
2. The `Text()` composable occupy *as much space, as it can.*

So, for example, it occupies the *whole screen,* if there are no other elements, in spite of the text consist *only of 1 character.*

So your question in its current form has no sense.

You probably wanted to solve one thing, but ask us about the other – see [What is the X-Y problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233676/356878) and possibly edit your question.